# Refer to another class inside a class

Tags: c++

Here is the situation. I have two classes inside two different files.

A.cpp:

```
#include "B.h" 
A::A(){
B foo; //B doesn't name a type
}
```

B.cpp:

```
Class B{
//code
};
```

How do I correctly construct an object of B inside A's constructor?(scoping issue) I tried

```
B::B foo //wrong
```

and why I can't directly construct an object of class B like I did above, B.h has been included. Thank you very much

Comment: What's in `B.h`? You should post that code, too.

Comment: what error message is the compiler giving you exactly?

Comment: actually there is no code at all in B file, just an empty class, I am thinking about the correct scope resolution in A to refer to an object of B

Comment: @Dai, B doesn't name a type. I am thinking the compiler is looking for a locally declared B class in File A, but there is none, so I was asking how to refer to the class B(scope)

Comment: There's nothing magic about including a file named `B.h`.  The importance of `#include` is that it causes the compiler to process everything in that file.  But your class isn't in `B.h`, it's in `B.cpp`, so it doesn't become available by `#include "B.h"`

Comment: @ClintHui: The contents of B.h are still important, as Ben Voight pointed out. Is B.h an empty file, or does it contain a class declaration? If it contains a class declaration, you should post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the class definition of `B` into the header file:

**b.h:**

```
#ifndef H_B_CLASS
#define H_B_CLASS

class B
{
    // member declarations
};

#endif
```

**a.cpp:**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

A::A() { B foo; /* ... */ }
```

**b.cpp:**

```
#include "b.h"

// B's member definitions
```

If there's nothing in class `B`, you can omit `b.cpp` and put the entire class definition into the header file.

Comment: Hello, it still complains DataSet does not name a type in my case. Here is what I am trying to do. the Main calls A's constructor which calls the B's constructor. i.e main->A->B, However, it won't construct an object with this line in A's constructor, **B foo**, the GCC compiler said "A::B foo" has initializer but incomplete type. Thank you

Comment: @ClintHui: Edit your post to include a complete, minimal, reproducible example of your error.

Answer (score 0):

If `B` is completely empty, as you say, then there's no public default constructor available.  You must at least define `B()` as a public member of `class B`, otherwise nobody can construct it.

Comment: Empty classes will implicitly give you a default constructor if needed. You can instantiate, copy, and assign to a `class C{};`. For the default constructor, the criteria is that it has no user-defined constructor.